# How to Compute the Pareto-front of this set?

Tags: number-theory, order-theory

I need to decide which solution is the best design, in order to do that I need to compare them. Lower energy used and lower weight is better. My initial idea was to order both the fields best to worst and chose based on which one finished higher but whats better 3rd and 2nd, or 1st and 4th?

The pareto front is a set of nondominated solutions, being chosen as optimal, if no objective can be improved without sacrificing at least one other objective.

1. **(Energy Used, Weight)**

   A  (30,20)

   B  (50,30)

   C (10,40)

   D (20,50)

   E (40,10)

[Diagram Showing the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zhrO.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you find an option which is clearly *not* nondominated?

Comment: I've tried comparing each of them but I can't find one which isn't dominated by another, (30,20) seems the best

Comment: What dominates (40, 10)?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Domination refers to *different solutions* - e.g. C dominates D since C is better than D in every way (both energy and weight are lower (= better) in C than in D). Can you find something which is better than (40,10) in every way?

Comment: But how do you know that E(40,10) is better than C(10,40)? When you said what dominates E(40,10) I meant to say that for example A(30,20) has lower Energy, but E has lower weight, so how can I chose when not one has 2 dominating values?

Comment: E is neither better or worse than C. You're not looking for a single solution; re-read the definition of "pareto front" (and note the word "**set**").

Comment: oh, so I need to create a set where there isn't a solution better than, so then would the pareto front be E,C since nothing dominates either of them?

Comment: E and C would certainly be in the pareto front - would they be the *only* things in the pareto front, though?

Comment: Crossposted (and more extensively answered) at [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108522/how-do-you-compute-the-pareto-front-of-a-set). Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a crosspost.

Answer (score 1):

The pareto front is not a single element. It is the set of elements which are all kind of optimal in the sense that no other element is better in ALL criterias.

Comment: so instead of ordering them 1-5 etc I should just be choosing like the 3 best?

Comment: You have two criteria. There will most likely not be a "best" element. You should remove thise elements which are inferiour with respect to both criterias.